# Created KnowledgeBase using Microsoft QnAMaker API is always empty

Tags: azure, postman, azure-qna-maker

so I am trying to create a new QnA for the Microsoft Bot Framework but for some reason I am able to able to create a Knowledgebase but it is always empty.

So here's the result from postman
[image: Postman]

Then I wait a while for all the process to finish and when to [www.qnamaker.ai](https://www.qnamaker.ai) to see if the knowledgebase is created and sure enough it is created.
[image]

But going into the knowledgebased itself, I found out it is empty.
[image]

I am stumped here and with their limited documentation I don't know what is happening here.

Hope someone can help me with this and thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found outed what's the issue with my code.

So I was pushing a string in the `id` param when it only accepts `number`. That's why my knowledge based is not being populated with the data I've created.